# Regex help: subdomain check

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

Hey I have a form where the person enters the subdomain like value.google.com and the entry would be "valid"

I want to run a regex check (I am absolutely horrible at regex) that does the following:

First Character: Cannot be symbol
Middle Characters: a-z, A-Z, and symbols - and . ONLY
Last character: Cannot be a symbol

I want it to spit out false if it fails the test.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

Also any other limitations do you guys think should be in there?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a character class. :)

- [a-zA-Z\-\.] would match characters of type "a-zA-Z-.".
- [a-zA-Z] would match characters of type "a-zA-Z".
- ^ means beginning of line
- $ means end of line
- + means "one or more times"

So what you are looking for is:
**^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\-\.]+[a-zA-Z]$**

And since you in PHP can set i-flag it becomes case insensitive and this code should work:

```
  if (preg_match("/^[a-z][a-z\-\.]+[a-z]$/i", "valid.google.com")) {
   echo "A match was found.";
  } else {
   echo "A match was not found.";
  }
```

*Tip: Should you not also include numbers? [a-z0-9]*

Comment: hey thanks alot. you are correct... I should include numbers.The thing is the "valid" string already comes without the .google.com so I wouldnt have to search the string. I simply want check that the "valid" string doesnt start or end with symbols and the middle chracters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, ., or - How would I do this?

Comment: `[A-Z0-9.-]` (instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]`) is enough. You already have set the `i` modifier, so it's already case-insensitive. No need to escape the dot inside a character class, and no need to escape the dash if you place it at the start or end of the character class.

Comment: Hey Tim if I break the string down to three parts, first character, middel and last character using substr can I then run a pregmatch on each one? the first and last character would be [a-zA-Z0-9] and the middle characters would be [a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If the TLD is always `com` you should be able to do with:

```
/^(.*)\.[^.]+\.com$/
```

This will match whatever's before the rightmost `.` character (excluding the `.com`).

However, you might want to do this with simple string operations instead ([`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)). Or, you could split on `.`:

```
function extract_sub($domain) {
        $parts = explode('.', $domain);

        return implode('.', array_slice($parts, 0, -2));
}
```

([Demo](http://www.ideone.com/vlxXR))

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably the most common situation.

```
$subdomain = "usersubdomain";

if(preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i", $subdomain)) {
   echo "Valid sub domain";
  }else{
   echo "Not a valid sub domain.";
  }
```

Comment: That won't quite match the rules that the original poster listed.