# Regular expression for valid subdomain in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

I'm attempting to validate a string of user input that will be used as a subdomain. The rules are as follows:

1. Between 1 and 63 characters in length (I take 63 from the number of characters Google Chrome appears to allow in a subdomain, not sure if it's actually a server directive. If you have better advice on valid max length, I'm interested in hearing it)
2. May contain a-zA-Z0-9, hyphen, underscore
3. May not begin or end with a hyphen or underscore

EDIT: From input below, I've added the following:
4. Should not contain consecutive hyphens or underscores.

Examples:

```
a => valid
0 => valid
- => not valid
_ => not valid
a- => not valid
-a => not valid
a_ => not valid
_a => not valid
aa => valid
aaa => valid
a-a-a => valid
0-a => valid
a&a => not valid
a-_0 => not valid
a--a => not valid
aaa- => not valid
```

My issue is I'm not sure how to specify with a RegEx that the string is allowed to be only one character, while also specifying that it may not begin or end with a hyphen or underscore.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551963/regex-help-subdomain-check

Comment: Thanks, the topic linked includes a full domain validity check, and I'm only looking for a string that is valid for use as a subdomain. Do you have advice on how to modify it to work? I can't seem to make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You <del>can't</del> can have underscores in <del>proper</del> subdomains, but do you need them? After `trim`ming your input, do a simple string length check, then test with this:

```
/^[a-z\d]+(-[a-z\d]+)*$/i
```

With the above, you won't get consecutive `-` characters, e.g. `a-bbb-ccc` passes and `a--d` fails.

```
/^[a-z\d]+([-_][a-z\d]+)*$/i
```

Will allow non-consecutive underscores as well.

---

**Update:** you'll find that, in practice, underscores are disallowed and all subdomains must start with a letter. The solution above does not allow internationalised subdomains (punycode). You're better of using this

```
/\A([a-z][a-z\d]*(-[a-z\d]+)*|xn--[\-a-z\d]+)\z/i
```

Comment: After thinking about it, I agree that allowing consecutive hyphens and underscores would make for very ugly subdomains. Appreciate the input. This works great.

Comment: I was thinking of domains which are more restrictive but I wouldn't bother allowing consecutive separators like your selected answer, they'll look ugly and won't add to usability/readablity.

Comment: this regex is what I need, but how to force min char length for the the full string. Tried different settings with {n,} at different places, bu nothing worked.

Comment: @webdeb As stated in my answer, do this before the regex, i.e. check the `length` property of the string.

Comment: `"111111" =~ /\A[a-z\d]+([-_][a-z\d]+)*$\Z/` this should not match, but matching

Comment: @SohairAhmad No, it should; the pattern is correct according to OP's specification. I have added an update to my answer, though. You need to [practice your regexen](http://rubular.com/).

Comment: @SohairAhmad No, it just met OP's specification.

Comment: @Walf not sure if I get the different between valid domain name and op's specification, but thanks.

Comment: @SohairAhmad OP wrote `0 => valid` and `0-a => valid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-\_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9])$/i
```

I've took it as a challenge to create a regex that should match only strings with non-repeating hyphens or underscores and also check the proper length for you:

```
/^([a-z0-9]([_\-](?![_\-])|[a-z0-9]){0,61}[a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9])$/i
```

The middle part uses a lookaround to verify that.

Comment: The original should work for 2 letter entries as well (that's why there's the `{0,61}`. Also the question mark can be omitted, I'll edit it out.

Comment: That will match `a___---_____--__--__-__----__---__whatever at the end` and `whatever at the start^&*^&^)^)_---_--abc`. If you insist on allowing awful subdomains filled with `-` and `_` then you need to put parenthesis on the or: `/^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{0,61}?[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])$/`

Comment: @justin `0-9` in a character class allows numerals.

Comment: @Lucas: I've edited it several times, better to reload SO before commenting :) @Justin: Fixed.

Comment: @Jakub thanks for modifying for numerals. This does what I was looking for but I'm also gonna agree with @Lucas's input on not allowing consecutive hyphens and underscores. His works great too.

Comment: @gsr I got challenged and made an interestig regexp ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Ruby regex syntax, but I'll assume it's like, say, Perl. Sounds like you want:

```
/^(?![-_])[-a-z\d_]{1,63}(?<![-_])$/i
```

Or if Ruby doesn't use the `i` flag, just replace `[-a-z\d_]` with `[-a-zA-Z\d_]`.

The reason I'm using `[-a-zA-Z\d_]` instead of the shorter `[-\w]` is that, while nearly equivalent, `\w` will allow special characters such as **ä** rather than just ASCII-type characters. That behavior can be optionally turned off in most languages, or you can allow it if you like.

Some more information on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

^[a-zA-Z]([-a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z\d])?$

This simply enforces the standard in an efficient way without backtracking. It does not check the length, but Regex is inefficient at things like that. Just check the string length (1 to 64 chars).

Answer (score -1):

`/[^\W\_](.+?)[^\W\_]$/i` should work for ya (try our http://rubular.com/ to test out regular expressions)

EDIT: actually, this doesn't check single/double letter/numbers. try `/([^\W\_](.+?)[^\W\_])|([a-z0-9]{1,2})/i` instead, and tinker with it in rubular until you get exactly what ya want (if this doesn't take care of it already).

Comment: Thanks, I've been using rubular and it's a great testing tool. I think the expression you gave has the same issue of not allowing strings less than 3 characters that I've been having. Also it appears to allow characters other than hyphens and underscores in the middle (a&a comes up valid). I'm also wondering if you left the ^ out of the beginning on purpose, and if so for what reason.

Comment: That matched `.nNGygyG(NG(NG966%&i.`, and would match a lot of other crap too. You need to read up on regex. PCRE sections of php manuals are quite useful.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas, I did forget to include zero match characters within the repetition match. Ignore my suggestion :)