# Ruby URI - matching a part of a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

I am using URI module in ruby to match a URL.

```
require 'uri'
url = URI"http://matchme.projects.foo.com"
```

Need to match the matchme part of the url and put it into a variable. The matchme part of the url will always be after http:// and before the next ".projects".

I am trying `url.scheme` which gives me "http", how to proceed from there and match my string.
The matchme part keeps changing all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regular expression like

```
  "http://matchme.projects.foo.com"[/http:\/\/([a-z0-9\-]*).*/,1]
  => matchme
```

or

if request object is available then

```
 request.subdomains[0]
```

will give you the deepest sub domain.

Comment: Although I initially thought URI would be useful. I think this was more efficient by just matching using regular expressions. Thanks

Comment: In case `matchme` could be `ma.tch.me` the better regex should be `[/http:\/\/(.*)\.projects.*/,1]`

Comment: update regular expression to work with all valid sub-domains. check my update.

Comment: [here is duscussion about valid subdomain and regex for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196640/regular-expression-for-valid-subdomain-in-ruby)